# Draw a resize square on top of a custom control

Tags: c#, resize, move

I would like to be able to draw a square on top of a custom control that has 8 handles that will allow the user to to resize it from any direction and move it at runtime.
This should look similar to the one on Visual Studio. (I need 10 reputation to post images)

Thanks in advance,
VBTheory

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: can you post what you've tried already ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, that's the problem, I'm fairly new to drawing and stuff so I hope someone can help me

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/